# Using inner_hits inside an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of documents which all contain an array of nested objects with important data. I want do to an aggregation on these which returns me the first document, last document, and all of the nested objects in that group. I can achieve everything in that list except for the nested objects.

Mapping:

```
"instances": {
"properties": {
   "aggField": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
   },
   "id": {
      "type": "integer"
   },
   "nestedObjs": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
         "key": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         },
         "value": {
            "type": "integer"
         }
      }
   },
   "timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "dateOptionalTime"
   }
}
```

}

Query:

```
{
"size" : 0,
"aggs" : {
    "agg-buckets" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "aggField",
            "size" : 10
        },
        "aggs": {
            "last-report": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 1
                }
            },
            "first-report": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "order": "asc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 1
                }
            },
            "nested-objs": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "nestedObjs",
                    "inner_hits": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with:

Parse Failure [Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [nested-objs].]

If I remove the "inner_hits" field it works ok. But it just gives me the document count and not the documents themselves.

What am I doing wrong?

E: I'm using ES version 1.7.1

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having exactly the same problem with Elastic 1.7.x.

Comment: Sorry, no. I was unable to solve this so went with different alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `inner_hits` is allowed in a `nested` aggregation (as opposed to a `nested` query)? I suspect that's what's causing the error.

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't (or didn't) error out. It just didn't return what I expected.